# How detect is input filled without required and withour placeholder?

Tags: html, css, input

Here 2 inputs, 1 requied.

```
<div class="form-item-input">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="mail"
    id="mail"
    placeholder=""
    required>
  <label for="mail">Email</label>
</div>

<div class="form-item-input">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    id="name"
    placeholder="">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
</div>
```

Css

```
  .input {
    & label {
      position: absolute;
      left: 3px;
      top: 7px;
      color: #959595;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: all ease .2s;
    }
  
    &:focus {
      & ~ label {
        top: -16px;
        left: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
    }
  }
```

I need to animate label when input is focused or filled with some text.

Pseudo `:valid` work only with required inputs.

Pseudo `:placeholder-shown` not working, because I don't have placeholders

Basically, I need that but without JS.
https://codepen.io/katrina-isabelle/pen/PQBqyq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just add a space placeholders:

```css
input{
 transition: all .5s;
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown), input:focus{
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-item-input">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="mail"
    id="mail"
    placeholder=" "
    required>
  <label for="mail">Email</label>
</div>

<div class="form-item-input">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    id="name"
    placeholder=" ">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude, without JS

Comment: Space as placeholdes, thought about that, but looks like crutch solution. Is there really nothing normal for this case in html css?